# MySql Service not starting

Tags: mysql

I was having mysql 5.1.x installed on my windows machine. Beacuse of some reason I needed 5.5.x or above. I uninstalled mysql 5.1.x and downloaded the 5.7.x version. I extracted and tried to install the service using below command and I got the response saying Service already exists. How to fix the issue?

C:\mysql-5.7.10\bin>mysqld --install
The service already exists!
The current server installed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You must run the command `sc delete {{MySQL}}` where `{{MySQL}}` is the name of the service.